# how do I render white liquids?

Tags: materials, fluid-simulation

I want it to look like these
[image]
if I set the glass shader color to white it just becomes transparent

Comment: is it for Eevee or Cycles?

Comment: @moonboots cycles

Comment: Are the liquid and the glass the same, or separate objects?

Comment: Have you tried a simple clear glass shader with a volume absorption volume shader? You could also try adjusting the roughness for the glass shader.

Comment: A stab in the dark here, but I would definitely try adding some subsurface scattering. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/sss.html

Comment: This is kind of subsurface scattering but with full path simulation and volume scattering, I doubt that Blender could make a feasible solution without writing a custom shader after trying a lot of built-in shader.

Answer (score 3):

I gave a try with this node setup, you need a mix between *Translucent/Transparent/Subsurface Scattering/Glossy/Glass* and at the end, plug the Principled Volume into the *Volume* socket of the *Material Output*:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You can change the opacity of the liquid by using both the Mix Shader between the Transparent and Translucent, and the Mix Shader between the Diffuse/Glossy and Transparent/Translucent mix. In the image below, I only adjusted the mix between the Transparent/Translucent. Left is 0.1 middle is 0.5, right is 0.9.

[image: Liquids]