Help Creating translucent liquid with density-based opacity
I'm trying to create a material for a liquid, specifically a ketchup spill, in Blender. My goal is to make it appear opaque in denser areas and translucent in less dense areas.
I've been experimenting with using a mix shader controlled by a factor derived from the Ambient Occlusion node. However, I've run into an issue where the areas that should be translucent turn black instead.

I have realized that when I reverse the order of the nodes I get the desired effect, but in the wrong part

I've tried adjusting various parameters, but I can't seem to resolve this issue. Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190914/how-do-i-render-white-liquids/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72495/create-a-gradient-effect-like-for-coffee https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107236/how-to-make-my-water-look-murky/
